# Angular 2 - redirect .js and .js.map files outside src

Tags: typescript, angular

My Scr files:

```
-a.ts  
-a.js.map  
-a.js
```

What I pretend on my src:

```
-a.ts
```

Into node_modules must be some folder where will be all my files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you compiling your ts files? Are you using command line to compile using tsc command? Are you using tsconfig.json?

you have to use --outDir switch in command line or use below in tsconfig.json file to get your compiled js and map files inside another folder names **dist**, you may use any folder name.

```
  "outDir":"dist"
```

If you dont need source map you may turn it off by setting below flag in tsconfig

```
  "sourceMap": false
```

you may read more about tsconfig.json on [Typescript site](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) or [Typescript book by basarat](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/alm/content/config/tsconfig.html)

**Update**

For **Visual studio 2013** you may configure out directory by checking "Redirect JavaScript output to directory" inside Typescript build tab on project properties and providing path there.

In **Visual studio 2015** you may do the above or it reads tsconfig file for the configuration. where you may provide configurations.

For **Visual studio Code**

you have to configure build task, one of the way is to configure tsconfig based task, it reads all the option in your tsconfig.json file. so you have to configure outDir in the tsconfig.json .

To configure task press F1 on windows(or equivalent on Mac) and type configure task then select Typescript - tsconfig.json, it will create a tasks.json and place into .vscode with all the configuration necessary.

you may read more about VS code tasks at [Tasks in VS code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks).

Comment: I dont need to compile my files. When I introduce a .ts file on visual studio automatically he introduces a .ts and .js file.

Comment: @Goldbones:  you might not, but Visual studio does compile typescript files. I have updated the answer with Visual studio options.

Comment: Ok...I have visual studio code and not just visual studio. It´s the same instructions?

Comment: @Goldbones: Nope for VS code instructions are different, updated the same in answer.